# `scipy.signal.residue` or `scipy.signal.residuez` using zeros-poles-gain representation of filters

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In Scipy [signal processing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) module there are two functions [`residue`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.residue.html#scipy.signal.residue) and [`resideuz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.residuez.html#scipy.signal.residuez) to calculate [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of rational transfer functions.

Both of those functions require polynomial coefficients of the numerator and denominator as input.  I was wondering if there is a version that accepts roots of numerator and denominator, i.e., zeros--poles--gain representation of the transfer function?

I actually think the calculation should be easier in that case.

Obviously, in theory, one can always go from one representation to another using [`tf2zpk`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.tf2zpk.html#scipy.signal.tf2zpk) and [`zpk2tf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.zpk2tf.html#scipy.signal.zpk2tf).  In practice, however, this transformation is not always reversible.  One can find examples of zeros, poles, and gain values (call them `z`, `p`, `k`) for which `tf2zpk(*zpk2tf(z, p, k))` does not reconstruct `z`, `p` and `k` precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Having the zeros and poles is indeed advantageous, as obtaining the numerator and denominator polynomial is rather straight forward, only a multiplication is involved. The reverse, on the other hand, is more complicated, as we have to find the roots of the polynomials. A typical approach, is to diagonalize the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), this is e.g. used by [numpy.roots](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html)

If we check the implementation of [residue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L2608-L2720), we see that, as expected, the first step is to calculate the poles. The rest is a more or less straight forward evaluation of the residues.

I don't know of any implementation, but it is quite simple to adjust the `scipy` implementation. The major improvement should be replacing the line `poles = np.roots(a)` by your poles. This avoids the matrix diagonalization. For the numerator, you can convert the zeros and gain to the numerator polynomial.

If you are eager, you can use the zeros and gain directly to calculate the residues, but I don't expect much improvement.

---

Disclaimer: I am certainly no expert on the topic, so don't blindly rely on my answer.